# Command Line alternative to IsoBuster

Tags: command-line, iso, emulation

I am trying to find a way to automate the process of merging multi-track `.bin` + `.cue` files into a single `.bin` and `.cue`.  I have a collection of PSX roms, and they all come in bin and cue format.  And I am trying to follow the directions [here](https://github.com/retropie/retropie-setup/wiki/Playstation-1#m3u-playlist-for-multi-disc-games) in order to create a "playlist" `.m3u` file.

It recommends merging the multi-track files (they are audio channels of the image) using IsoBuster to mount the `.cue` file, then "burn" it to a singular `.bin` file.

I don't have Windows, and I have over 200 games I would need to do this for.  So if I could automate it that would be great.

Anyone have any suggestions for CLI tools to use?

I've read previous answers about `bin2iso` and `bchunk` but apparently they don't work for `.bin` files with multiple track files.  I.e. the sound won't work when the game is played.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

I have published a tool for merging the multi-bin files into a single .bin/.cue pair.

You can find it [Here](http://github.com/jordond/romtool)

---

**Original Answer:**

For those also looking for a solution.  I have come across a python script that seems to work.  So far I've tested it with a couple files and it seems to be working.

You can find the script [here](https://github.com/putnam/binmerge).